# Using pyramid versus webapp2 on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

From a development and compatibility standpoint, is there any issue with using the Pyramid framework instead of the built-in webapp2 on google app engine?

From what I understand any WCGI compatible framework will work.

Is deployment the exact same process?

Comment: This question isn't really appropriate for SO, it's not about a programming question but more about recommendations.  Having said that I use pyramid on appengine all the time, I have also used other light weigh frameworks.  In fact I have never used webapp2 (or webapp) for any appengine app and I have been developing on appengine since 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The Pylons Project website has a cookbook showing you how to do it. http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/deployment/gae_buildout.html